# Can not export renderer text using highcharts/highstock when click range selector

Tags: export, highcharts

I have a question related the chart export.

Please see [Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dodoflying/UGbpJ/1/)

I added a text label using `chart.renderer.text` on the Yaxis for the latest value of series.

If I directly click button "Export Image". There is no problem, the label can be displayed. I'm using the following way to export image. draw_labels() is a function to draw yaxis label.

```
$("#b").click(function () {
      chart.exportChart(null, {
            chart: {
                       backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                       width: 972,
                       height: 480,
                       events: {
                           load: function () {
                               draw_labels(this);
                            }
                           }
                        }
                  });
        });
```

**The problem is after I clicked range selector or change Xaxis range. When I try to export the
chart to image, there is no labels are drawn. The following is the complete code.**

The following is the complete code:

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
        chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                events: {
                    load: function () {
                        draw_labels(this);
                        $("#b").click(function () {
                            chart.exportChart(null, {
                                chart: {
                                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                                    width: 972,
                                    height: 480,
                                    events: {
                                        load: function () {
                                            draw_labels(this);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL',
                id: 'test',
                data: data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }],

            navigator: {
                enabled: false
            },

            yAxis: {
                tickWidth: 0,
                id: 'value_axis',
                type: 'linear',
                gridLineColor: '#EEE',

                lineColor: '#D0CDC9',
                lineWidth: 0,
                minorTickInterval: null,

                opposite: true,

                offset: 0

            },

            xAxis: {
                events: {
                    afterSetExtremes: function (e) {
                        console.log('test');
                        $('[id="test_text"]').remove();
                        draw_labels(chart);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });



    function draw_labels(chart) {
        $(chart.series).each(function (i, serie) {

            var s_id = serie.options.id;

            var temp_id = s_id;

            var point = serie.points[serie.points.length - 1];

            if (point) {

                var pre, post;

                if (point.y) {
                    var last_value_dis = (point.y).toFixed(1);


                    yaxis_name = 'value_axis';

                    //Get Yaxis position
                    var y_axis = chart.get(yaxis_name);
                    offsite_yaxis = 0;
                    element_text = chart.renderer.text(
                    //the text to render
                    '<span style="font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;color:' + serie.color + ';">' + last_value_dis + '</span>',
                    //the 'x' position
                    y_axis.width + y_axis.offset,
                    //the 'y' position
                    chart.plotTop + point.plotY + 3).attr({
                        id: temp_id + '_text',
                        zIndex: 999
                    }).add();
                }
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: It seems like the setExtremes event handler also runs when you do export after selecting the range. It then runs with the original chart width, which is strange... Perhaps you can try to filter on this somehow.

Comment: Hi Torstein, could you provide a Fiddle example? I really don't know how to do this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipinroshan/ay5GE/1/), I have fixed it for you. Here is a saved image:

[image: Exported Image]Following changes have been done:

1. Added a redraw event to your exportchart

   ```
   redraw: function () {
       $("#test_text").remove() ;
       draw_labels(this);
   }
   ```
2. Changed this line in `afterSetExtremes`

   ```
   $('[id="test_text"]').remove();
   ```

   to

   ```
   $("#test_text").remove() ;
   ```

   Earlier one was not working as expected, so I had to change it.

Comment: Thanks! I feel it is a better solution. Could you help to explain why you add `redraw: function () {
    $("#test_text").remove() ;
    draw_labels(this);
}`? I feel in your code already has `load: function () {
                                            draw_labels(this);
                                        },`. In addition, why can not use `$('[id="test_text"]').remove();`?

Comment: `load` event is fired once when the graph is initialized. `redraw` on the other hand is fired whenever axis, series or points are modified. Also `$("#test_text").remove() ;` matches only one element (the first one) with id `test_text` and removes it but `$('[id="test_text"]').remove();` matches multiple elements with the same id.  For some reason this line was interfering with removing and adding of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with disappearing text is related with id, when I removed it, label appears. But then I came across second issue, wrong y position. So i declare `global variable`, then when you call your function, set position of label, and use in chart exporting this variable. As a result label is exported correct.

http://jsfiddle.net/UGbpJ/11/